# Do you think the output voltage is caused by an old capacitor?

Tags: power-supply, rectifier, fault

I have a vacuum tube power supply which isn't producing the correct output voltage. I have removed the tube and all that is left is the transformer, inline 22 ohm resistor, CR201/202, R202/203 and C201/202. I simulated it on LTspice and have also included that below. Currently the voltage across C202 is ~90Vdc. I suspect it's due to the capacitors being old and failing - but does anyone have any experience with old caps? Or suggestions? I did increase the voltage from the transformer to 200VAC as that is what the measured value was.
[image: schematic of tube supply from datasheet]

Comment: I can not understand what this question is asking. Add a bit more clarity please.

Comment: that's an inline 47 ohm resistor ... 22 is associated with the transformer

Comment: What is the unit used fro C201 and C202? 20 µF or 20 nF? Are these capacitors wet electrolytic? How old is the supply?

Comment: what should the voltage be?

Comment: @Uwe C201/C202 are filter caps, 20uF.

Comment: Can you tell use what model the supply is or link to a full schematic?

Comment: Have you verified that test points #22 to #24 measure close to **195V AC** ? And that AC voltage from #24 to the junction of R201 and CR201 is similar?

Comment: Look at the arrowhead, the -157.8 V is at the positive terminal of C201. Something seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If the capacitors are original they are almost certainly bad. If they've dried out you'll get a lot of ripple and low average DC voltage. Old tube equipment that hasn't been used in a long time should be powered up slowly with a variac as old capacitors that have failed shorted can destroy the transformer.

The 47\$\Omega\$ resistor should be checked as it's value may have increased. Carbon composition resistor's values go up as they age, so if it's one of them there's a good chance it's value is off.

This is a voltage doubler circuit, the positive half cycle charges C201, the negative half cycle charges C202, they're in series with balancing resistors across them so the voltages across them add. I can't tell from the part of the schematic shown how it's connected to the rest of the circuit.